# What kind of security loopholes could this creative way of sanitizing input, possibly face? (if any)

Tags: php, security, input

The standard way of sanitizing input would be to use commands such as

`$url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);`

`$strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');`

`preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);`

`echo htmlentities($str);`

However, I *like* it when my users are able to use nice things like parentheses, carats, quotes, etc in their inputs, comments/usernames/etcetc. Since HTML renders codes such as  `&#40;` into symbols such as `(`, I was hoping to use this alternative approach to sanitizing their input.

Before I embarked on writing a function to do this for possibly harmful characters such as `(` or `;` or `<` (so injections such as sneaky `eval()` or `<text/javascript>` would not work) I tried searching up previous people's attempts at doing this type of sanitization.

**I found none.**

This makes me think that I must be clearly overlooking some incredibly obvious security flaw in my "creative" sanitization method.

1. I will not be using this function as the primary way to protect my mySQL database. I have the new `mysqli` class for that. Adding this sanitization overtop of the mysqli separation of input & query seems like a nice idea, though.
2. I am using a completely different function to clean up URLs. Those require a different approach.
3. This function *will* be used for user input to be displayed on the page, though.

So .... what could I possibly be missing? I KNOW there's gotta be something wrong with this idea since no one else uses it, right?! Is it possible to "re-render the rendered text" or something else horrific and obvious? My pretty little function so far:

- Takes input strings like `meep';) drop table` or
  `alert(eval('document.body.inne' + 'rHTML'));`

  ```
  function santitize_data($data)    {
  //explode the string
  //do a replacement for each character separately. Only do one replacement.
  //dont do it with preg_replace because that function searches through a string in multiple passes 
  //and replaces already-replaced characters, resulting in horrific mishmash.
  //put it back together with + signs iterating through array variables   

  $patterns = array();
  $patterns[0] = "'";
  $patterns[1] = '"';
  $patterns[2] = '!';
  $patterns[3] = '\\';
  $patterns[4] = '#';
  $patterns[5] = '%';
  $patterns[6] = '&';
  $patterns[7] = '$';
  $patterns[8] = '(';
  $patterns[9] = ')';
  $patterns[10] = '/';
  $patterns[11] = ':';
  $patterns[12] = ';';
  $patterns[13] = '|';
  $patterns[14] = '<';
  $patterns[15] = '>';
  $patterns[16] = '{';
  $patterns[17] = '}';

  $replacements = array();
  $replacements[0] = '&#39;';
  $replacements[1] = '&#34;';
  $replacements[2] = '&#33';
  $replacements[3] = '&#92;';
  $replacements[4] = '&#35;';
  $replacements[5] = '&#37;';
  $replacements[6] = '&#38;';
  $replacements[7] = '&#36;';
  $replacements[8] = '&#40;';
  $replacements[9] = '&#41;';
  $replacements[10] = '&#47;';
  $replacements[11] = '&#58;';
  $replacements[12] = '&#59;';
  $replacements[13] = '&#124;';
  $replacements[14] = '&lt;';
  $replacements[15] = '&gt;';
  $replacements[16] = '&#123;';
  $replacements[17] = '&#125;';

  $split_data = str_split($data);

  foreach ($split_data as &$value) {
      for ($i=0; $i<17; $i++){
          //testing
          //echo '<br> i='.$i.' value='.$value.' patterns[i]='.$patterns[$i].' replacements[i]='.$replacements[$i].'<br>';
          if ($value == $patterns[$i]) { 
              $value = $replacements[$i];
              $i=17;    }    }    }
  unset($value); // break the reference with the last element

  $data = implode($split_data);

  //a bit of commented out code .. was using what seemed more logical before ... preg_replace .. but it parses the string in multiple passes ):
  //$data = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $data);

  return $data;

  } //---END function definition of santitize_data
  ```
- Spits out result strings like `meep&#39;&#59;&#41; drop table` or
  `alert&#40;eval&#40;&#39;document.body.inne&#39; + &#39;rHTML&#39;&#41;&#41;&#59;`
- and the user sees these things rendered in the browser like like `meep';) drop table` and
  `alert(eval('document.body.inne' + 'rHTML'));`

Comment: "Standard way of sanitizing input"? There is none. And 9 times out of 10 when someone uses the word "sanitize" -- they are doing something wrong or at least misguided. This question also seems misguided.

Comment: So... why not just use `htmlentities`? Does it not do exactly what you want it to do? (Make sure to use `ENT_QUOTES`.)

Comment: there is no One True Sanitization function. It's essentially impossible to cover all cases, because many of the cases are mutually exclusive. You have to target your particular usage case and escape/sanitize for that. escaping for sql is utterly useless if the text is going into a browser environment. and html escaping is worse than useless if going into an sql context.

Comment: `htmlentities` only parses out a small handful of characters, not the full harmful array or possibilities.  ):

Comment: @cake: And can you explain (perhaps by example) exactly why the array of possibilities is harmful?

Comment: Thanks for the comments on the fact that there is no "standard" or "true" way to sanitize. I'm new to this and I honestly did not know that because I saw everyone using very very similar `preg_replace` functions. Even small recommendations help!

Comment: @cake Which 'harmful array of possibilities' does it not handle? Is this not directed towards producing HTML output?

Comment: You are going down the completely wrong path. Sure, sometimes (not often) it makes sense to massage your input. But what you need to do most of the time is *properly encode the output*.

Comment: There is input text. If you are just storing it, in a database and displaying it again later. Then 1) use prepared queries on input and 2) 'escape' it using. 'htmlentities' on output. All will be fine. If you have to interpret the input then some 'sanitizing' and 'validation' is essential.

Comment: @Jon  - many of these characters seem to be useful for XSS or various injection attempts. For example a user could be very sneaky about how they input javascript into a comment or a forum section. Like this dude's attack on myspace many years ago: http://namb.la/popular/tech.html

Comment: Why change the input? I like to know I have stored the actual data the user submitted.

Comment: Just saw the new comment - @jon - any pointers towards good resources on how to 'properly encode the output' or the 'right path' ? I've been trying to read articles about this sort of thing online for a month or two now, but since you seem to be telling me something new, I would definitely appreciate a pointer in the more proper direction!

Comment: So basically, storing no matter WHAT text - is safe (as long as I put it IN safely using mysqli or something similar) - and I must be concerned only with OUTPUTTING it safely? Is that the direction you're trying to point me toward? That does make sense. Thank you!

Comment: @cake yes. As long as you use UTF8, proper prepared statements and never concat variable data into the query string then the input process is safe. Then you need to ensure that the output will be safe as well (using htmlentities or similar).

Comment: You're all very helpful thank you. I'd like to accept one of you guys as an actual answer. Could one of you post something like a summary of the comments you've said? It's perfect for an answer to this small question - I'll check it off as the real answer.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Post an answer as to what you actually did. It will help others. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: @developerwjk - I simply chose an array of characters commonly used in javascript, php, and html code. I admit I went a bit overboard because I wanted as many things as possible to be escaped. ! is commonly used in expressions such as `if ($cake!=1) {...` and I was thinking of simply escaping out all characters such as + = < > ! etc. Now that I think about it more calmly, yeah, escaping out an exclamation point is a bit paranoid.

Comment: What's harmful about `!`, `:`, or `{`, `}`?  For SQL injection `'` and variations are harmful, so you'll use parameterized queries to solve that. For html/javascript injection `<` and `>` are harmful, so you'll replace those (in the output) with the HTML entities `&lt; &gt;`, and `"` with `&quot;` to avoid values breaking free of attributes in HTML by closing the attribute early.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent -  but one of you people should get rewarded with reputation for helping me :/ .... I mean, you guys actually took the time to explain several very important things...

Comment: @cake: Actually the way I like to see it, *you are only ever concerned about your output*. I prefer to regard "storing in database" as "sending output to a system other than your app, which in this instance happens to be a database". This is something you will do all the time. Usually you only have to work with the actual input when you need to validate or filter it (e.g. strip spaces from credit card number), which is not as often.

Comment: Was fun. We all like sharing knowledge like this. We are glad that you appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without analyzing your code I can tell you that there is a high probability that you've overlooked something that an attacker could use to inject their own code.

The main threat here is [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) - you shouldn't need to "sanitize" to insert data into a database. You either use parameterised queries or you correctly encode characters that the database query language confers special meaning to *at the point of entry* into your database (e.g. `'` character). XSS is normally dealt with by encoding at the *point of output*, however if you want to allow rich text then you need to take a different approach which is what I believe you are looking to achieve here.

Remember there is no magic function that sanitizes input in a generic manner - it very much depends on how and where it is used to determine whether it is safe or not in that context. (This bit added so if anyone searches and finds this answer then they are up to speed - I think you're already on top of this though.)

Complexity is the main enemy of security. If you cannot determine whether your code is safe or not it is too complicated and a sufficiently motivated attacker with enough time will find a way round your sanitization methods.

### What can you do about this?

If you want to allow your users to enter rich text you could either allow [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) to allow users to insert a limited, safe subset of HTML via your own conversion functions or you could allow HTML entry and run the content through a *tried and tested* solution such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). Now, HTML Purifier won't be perfect and I'm sure that ([another](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/39709/exploit)) flaw will be found in it at some point in the future.

### How to guard against this?

If you implement a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) on your site, this will prevent any successfully injected script code from executing in the browser. See here for [current browser support for CSP](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy). Don't be tempted to just use one of these methods - a good security model has layered security so if one control is circumvented, the other can catch it.

[Google have now implemented CSP in Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/reject-unexpected-content-security.html) to ensure any HTML email received cannot try anything sneaky to launch an XSS attack.